# Remove all entries from collection, which are found in different collection using linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Lets say we have two lists:

```
List<string> listA = new List<string>{"a", "c"};
List<string> listB = new List<string>{"a", "a", "b", "c", "d"};
```

And we want to remove from listB all duplicates with listA.

listA should be left untouched

listB should be left with elements {"b", "d"}

An obvious solution would be to iterate with loops, but I'm wondering how this can be done with System.Linq one-liner?

Maybe something like...

```
listB.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals(??));
```

Or...

```
listA.ForEach(key => listB.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals(key))); // cannot convert string[] to void
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0):

```
listB = listB.Except(listA).ToList();
```

a less efficient LINQ version:

```
listB = listB.Where(b => !listA.Contains(b)).ToList();
```

a non LINQ version which does not need to create a new list:

```
listB.RemoveAll(listA.Contains);
```

Answer (score 2):

**A possibly more performant version of @TimSchmelter's non-LINQ `RemoveAll` uses a `HashSet`:**

```cs
var hashA = new HashSet<string>(listA);
listB.RemoveAll(hashA.Contains);
```